# Labeled slider for ListAnimate

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, animation

Is it possible to have a labeled slider in `ListAnimate`? Example: Let's say I have

```
ListAnimate[Table[Plot[Sin[n x], {x, 0, 10}], {n, 5}]]
```

but I'd like the slider to show the name of the iterator (`n` in this case), and its current value, the way this could be done in `Manipulate` with a command like

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[n x], {x, 0, 10}], {{n, 1, n}, 1, 5, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Alternatively, perhaps even better, I could not show a slider at all, and instead add a text label (or some fancy graphic) showing the information I want as a graphics object (probably using `Show`). To be clear, I know how to add these elements to the graphic, but how do I get entirely rid of the slider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can replace the slider with a [`Clock`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clock.html):

```
DynamicModule[{n},
 Dynamic[n = Clock[{1, 5, 1}, 2];
  Plot[Sin[n x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotLabel -> n]
  ]
 ]
```

[image: GIF]

Comment: Hah, that's interesting! I would have never thought of this, thanks!